# android change wallpaper

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wallpaper

I'm trying to change wallpaper on galaxy sIII (ICS os) device I'm using 1280x1440 jpeg image by this code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

....

Bitmap m = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setBitmap(m);
```

which is not working and following not working also:

```
Bitmap m = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.data_img);
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setBitmap(m);
```

but when i use this:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setResource(data_img);
```

it was work perfectly but my case is download some image data save it as bitmap then set it as wallpaper. so loading resources is not functional in my case.

any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: are you getting any exception?? Did you try putting the Log statements??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

You have to use `public void setStream (InputStream data)` method:

```
InputStream ins = new URL("absolute/path/of/image").openStream();
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
wpm.setStream(ins);
```

OR, if you have image URI then use:

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
wpm.setResource(Uri.of.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Tudor Luca its working fine..

```
ins = new URL("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/gst/chhota.jpg").openStream();
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
wpm.setStream(ins);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
  private static boolean connectToNewWifiConfig(final WifiConfiguration wc, Context context)
    {
        wifi = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        boolean success = false;
        final int actNetId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        String prevNetworkSSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        int netId = wifi.addNetwork(wc);
        if (netId != ApplicationConstants.INVALID_NETWORK_ID)
        {
            success = wifi.saveConfiguration();
        }
        return success;
    }
```

it works for me make sure you pass right wificonfiguration ,  wificonfiguration  will contain

```
wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = "\"".concat(networkSSID).concat("\"");
        wifiConfig.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifiConfig.hiddenSSID = true;
        wifiConfig.priority = 40;
```